# what's the best regex that will capture these elements?

Tags: regex

Given input such as the following (where there could be any number of comma separated values; in this example only 3)

```
Abc (xyz) asd 123 - 1 MMM, xcz8c.8x - 5 MMMs, hello - world - 1 MMM
```

What's the regular expression that will capture the following 3 elements:

```
  Abc (xyz) asd 123
  xcz8c.8x
  hello - world
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Abc (xyz) asd 123 - 1 MMM, xcz8c.8x - 5 MMMs, hello - world - 1 MMM'
>>> re.findall(r'[ |,]*(.*?) - \d+ MMMs?', s)
['Abc (xyz) asd 123', 'xcz8c.8x', 'hello - world']
```

Comment: your regex does this trick. Can you please explain why .*? solves the problem?

Comment: (.*?) is lazy - meaning it tries 0 characters, then 1 character, then 2 and so on until the rest of the regex matches. (.*) is greedy, meaning it tries MAX characters, then MAX-1 characters, then MAX-2 and so on until the rest of the regex matches.

Answer (score 1):

```
([^,]*?)\s-\s\d+\sMMMs?
```

This might not be the best, but I've tested it [here](http://rubular.com/r/CBaVexW6NL).

Comment: I need to familiarize myself more with the *? quantifier. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSmith That is called [reluctant quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html). If you don't put `?` there, it would match the entire input.